# how to use prevent default on Elm Browser.Event.onKeyDown

Tags: event-handling, elm

**Please Note: I could not a find a solution that could work here, so I used ports for the same.**

I need to use Browser.Events.onKeyDown for which I have also written a decoder, I need to create some shortcuts for my web app thus I need to prevent default behavior of Meta key (on Mac) and Ctrl key (on other Os)

In my Subscription method I am using the following. 
But there is no exposed way of using prevent Default.

```
let
            decoder : Decode.Decoder Msg
            decoder =
               keyDecoder
                    |> Decode.andThen
                        (\( keyCode, ctrlKey ) ->
                                case keyCode of
                                    39 ->
                                       Decode.succeed <| ShortCutNext

                                    37 ->
                                        Decode.succeed <| ShortCutPrevious

                                     _ ->
                                        Decode.fail ""

                    )
    in
    Sub.batch
        [ Browser.Events.onKeyDown  decoder]



keyDecoder : Decode.Decoder ( Int, Bool )
keyDecoder =
    Decode.map2 (\a -> \b -> ( a, b ))
        (Decode.field "keyCode" Decode.int)
        (Decode.field "metaKey" Decode.bool)
```

**Note: The event is on the page itself and not on any element such as textarea thus Html.Events.custom "keydown" options decoder is not applicable.**